# React JS How to display component onclick, but not in App.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

React JS How to display component onclick, but not in App.js

This will be in App.js

```
var [clicks, setClicks] = useState(false)
    return(<>
    {clicks && <Component />} //this will display if clicks are true
    <button onClick={function(){setClicks(true)}}>click me<button/>
    </>)
```

But how to do this if i dont have UseState in another file not in App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Redux, you can use the same state on more than one componen on different pages.

Comment: React Redux: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Comment: Can i do without adding new stuff just react?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it
1.You need to lift up the state to App.js. pass the state as props to the components where you want to use.
2.You need to use state management tool like Redux.